# how to solve C# Json Serialization parsing in javascript with quoutes?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, serialization

I am serializing a C# Class AnnouncementClass

```
public class AnnouncementClass
{
    public string application;
    public List< AnnoucementsMessages > annoucements = new List<AnnoucementsMessages>();
}
public class AnnoucementsMessages
{
    public string message;
    public string startdate;
    public string priority;
 }
```

using the serializing method

```
string jsonboj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(announcementClass);
```

after that I write the json in the javascript by using the <%# > Tag and perform a page.databind() in the page and later in javascript y I use Json.Parse(jsonObj) to generate the json file

but that's giving me a problem

if in the message part i insert a double quoute it breakes the json.parse, even if i try to scape it.

Is there a proper way to translate the json to the javascript side? 
do i need to replace something before the c# serialization ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried replacing `"` with `\"` like this: `jsonboj = jsonboj.Replace("\"", "\\\"");`?

Comment: yes, i'lll paste the resulting javascript text, 
event the page jsonlint tells me it is a correct json

Comment: found the solution, 

I had to replace with ;quot instead of \"  

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, thank you

when parsing , Javascript will reduce all the scapes so, using \" = " and \\="

so i had to replace the \" with ;quot

Comment: What about other characters like `<` or `>`  that may happen in your json?

Comment: the JavaScriptSerializer().serialize() took care of those cases without problems

Comment: no, it didn't the JavaScriptSerializer().serialize() left the " as \" and that would not work for a string in javascript, please refrain from doing absurd comments for your lack of understanding. is pretty clear the problem, and also the solution

Comment: @user3692679: `\"` is entirely correct *for JavaScript strings*. Are you worried about *HTML* escaping perhaps?